# string match: words + characters

Tags: r, string, string-matching

I'm trying to search a dataframe to match a string, where I made an object from a column filled with notes.

As an example:

I'm looking for any row with notes that might match

```
mph_words<-c(">10", "> 10", ">20", "> 20")
```

And a row of code may resemble:

```
> lc_notes[1703]
[1] "collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts >20 mph."
```

As you can see, some of the notes have spaces between "<" or ">" and the number so using strsplit to search wouldn't be ideal because I do need to keep the "<"/">" with the number.

I've tried

```
> mph_words %in% lc_notes[2000]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> pmatch(mph_words, lc_notes[1703])
[1] NA NA NA NA

grepl(lc_notes[1703],mph_words)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> str_detect(mph_words,lc_notes[1703])
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> for (word in 1:length(mph_words)){
+   print(str_extract(mph_words[word],lc_notes[1703]))
+ }
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
```

and I'm not sure what to try next. If it's a regex expression, could you possibly just explain it in your answer? I'm trying to understand regex better.

*Edit*
I'm trying to print out rows that specifically have one of the characters in mph_words. So, the code would search each row in my lc_notes and print row 1703.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the fast help and more importantly, code explanation! @G5W -- thanks for all the edits but keeping the # was important because the value  of mph matters for the next part of the code.

Comment: @nate thanks! I should have clarified better (still learning how to ask questions) but lc_notes had ambiguous spaces between ">"/"<" , which is why I was trying to write different ways to account for that in mph_words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `apply` with  `stringr::str_detect` for this:

```
lc_notes <- c("collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts >20 mph.",
              "collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts > 20 mph.",
              "collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts of 20 mph.")
mph_words<-c(">10", "> 10", ">20", "> 20")

sapply(lc_notes, function(x) any(str_detect(x, mph_words)))

collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts >20 mph. 
                                                                    TRUE 
collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts > 20 mph. 
                                                                    TRUE 
collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts of 20 mph. 
                                                                   FALSE
```

`sapply` will loop through each element of the `lc_notes` vector, applying the test to each. Then by using `any`, we simplify the vector to a single logical value.

If you want the row numbers, rather than a logical vector, use the `which` function:

```
unname(which(sapply(lc_notes, function(x) any(str_detect(x, mph_words)))))
[1] 1 2
```

I used `unname` here to highlight that the vector this returns is the index of the items in `lc_notes` that match any of the regex patterns. You can also do the opposite and call `names` on it to jut get the text of the row:

```
names(which(sapply(lc_notes, function(x) any(str_detect(x, mph_words)))))
[1] "collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts >20 mph." 
[2] "collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts > 20 mph."
```

---

If you want a simpler regex, that matches with or without spaces, use the `?` optional quantifier on the space character:

```
mph_words<-c("> ?10", "> ?20")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was hoping for! I really appreciate the ? option, names/unname option especially!

Answer (score 3):

Edited to match edited question:
To find the row numbers, use `grep`

```
grep("[<>]\\s*\\d+\\b",  lc_notes)
```

`[<>]` matches either < or >
`\\s*` allows optional whitespace
`\\d`  matches the following numbers.

grep will give the numbers of the lines that match.

Comment: I just tried copy + paste your code but got this:                                                                
> sub(".*([<>]\s*\d+\b).*", "\\1", lc_notes)
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "".*([<>]\s"                          could you explain your code? Thanks!

Comment: This was the error I got: Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "".*([<>]\s"

Comment: Fixing that  now.  Try the new version.

Comment: Thanks! I got a print-out but I'm clarifying my question. Thanks for the regex explanation--that was VERY helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `strsplit` and `lapply`

```
# standardize (get rid of white spaces between <,> and digits in mph_words
mph_words <- unique(gsub('([<>])\\s{0,}(\\d+)', '\\1\\2', mph_words, perl = TRUE))        
# match 
check <- lapply(1:length(lc_notes), 
                function (k) any(mph_words %in% unlist(strsplit(lc_notes[k], ' '))))
check
# [[1]]
# [1] TRUE

# [[2]]
# [1] TRUE

# [[3]]
# [1] FALSE

# Finally printing the indices with a match
which(unlist(check))
# [1] 1 2
```

with the data

```
mph_words <- c(">10", "> 10", ">20", "> 20")  
lc_notes <- "collected 1.667 man-hr total. mostly cloudy, windy with gusts >20 mph."
lc_notes <- c(lc_notes, 'test >10', '>15')
```